# Lie algebra representation descends to associative algebra rep

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

$\mathfrak{gl}(n,\mathbb{C})$ is a Lie algebra with bracket given by the commutator. It can be induced by the associative algebra structure on ${\rm End}(n,\mathbb{C})$.

Representations of the associative algebra ${\rm End}(n,\mathbb{C})$ will obviously be representations of the induced Lie algebra, but are there representations of the Lie algebra which are not representations of the associative algebra?

Is there a classification of representations which belong to both? Actually, I'm mostly interested in the adjoint rep of the lie algebra. It seems to me that this would not correspond to a rep of the associative algebra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The matrix algebra $\mathrm{End}_\mathbf{C}(\mathbf{C}^n)$ is semi-simple, with a unique irreducible representation (namely, $\mathbf{C}^n$).

However, the category of representations of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{gl}_n(\mathbf{C})$ is far from semi-simple. Moreover, there are plenty of infinite-dimensional irreducible representations of the Lie algebra (which are a fortiori *not* coming from irreducible representations of the matrix algebra). The adjoint representation of the Lie algebra is finite dimensional, and equal to the direct sum of the space of scalar matrices (on which the Lie algebra acts trivially) and the space of trace $0$ matrices (an ideal isomorphic to the special linear Lie algebra). These are both irreducible.

In sum, the representation theory of the two could not be more different. The representation theory of the Lie algebra is, however, the same as that of a certain associative algebra: its *universal enveloping algebra*.